# Flutter State Management with Bloc/Cubit

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, cubit

for many of you this is an obvious / stupid question, but I've come to a point where I don't have a clue anymore. I have real difficulties understanding State Management with Bloc / Cubit.

Expectation: I have a page with a ListView (recipe_list) of all recipes and an 'add' button. Whenever I click on a ListItem or the 'add' button I go to the next page (recipe_detail). On this page I can create a new recipe (if clicked the 'add' button before), update or delete the existing recipe (if clicked on ListItem before). When I click the 'save' or 'delete' button the Navigator pops and I go back to the previous page (recipe_list). I used Cubit to manage the state of the recipe list. My expectation is that the ListView updates automatically after I clicked 'save' or 'delete'. But I have to refresh the App to display the changes.

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Recipe Demo',
      home: BlocProvider<RecipeCubit>(
        create: (context) => RecipeCubit(RecipeRepository())..getAllRecipes(),
        child: const RecipeList(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

recipe_list.dart

```
class RecipeList extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecipeList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecipeListState createState() => _RecipeListState();
}

class _RecipeListState extends State<RecipeList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 24.0
          ),
          color: const Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 32.0,
                      bottom: 32.0
                    ),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text('Recipes'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: BlocBuilder<RecipeCubit, RecipeState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        if (state is RecipeLoading) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        } else if (state is RecipeError) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Icon(Icons.close),
                          );
                        } else if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
                          final recipes = state.recipes;
                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: recipes.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return BlocProvider<RecipeCubit>(
                                          create: (context) => RecipeCubit(RecipeRepository()),
                                          child: RecipeDetail(recipe: recipes[index]),
                                        );
                                      }
                                  ));
                                },
                                child: RecipeCardWidget(
                                  title: recipes[index].title,
                                  description: recipes[index].description,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Text('Loading recipes error');
                        }
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: 'addBtn',
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return BlocProvider<RecipeCubit>(
                          create: (context) => RecipeCubit(RecipeRepository()),
                          child: const RecipeDetail(recipe: null),
                        );
                      }
                    ));
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

recipe_detail.dart

```
class RecipeDetail extends StatefulWidget {

  final Recipe? recipe;

  const RecipeDetail({Key? key, required this.recipe}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecipeDetailState createState() => _RecipeDetailState();
}

class _RecipeDetailState extends State<RecipeDetail> {

  final RecipeRepository recipeRepository = RecipeRepository();

  final int _recipeId = 0;
  late String _recipeTitle = '';
  late String _recipeDescription = '';

  final recipeTitleController = TextEditingController();
  final recipeDescriptionController = TextEditingController();

  late FocusNode _titleFocus;
  late FocusNode _descriptionFocus;

  bool _buttonVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.recipe != null) {
      _recipeTitle = widget.recipe!.title;
      _recipeDescription = widget.recipe!.description;
      _buttonVisible = true;
    }

    _titleFocus = FocusNode();
    _descriptionFocus = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    recipeTitleController.dispose();
    recipeDescriptionController.dispose();

    _titleFocus.dispose();
    _descriptionFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 24.0
          ),
          color: const Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: IconButton(
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    focusNode: _titleFocus,
                    controller: recipeTitleController..text = _recipeTitle,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter recipe title',
                      border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                    onSubmitted: (value) => _descriptionFocus.requestFocus(),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    focusNode: _descriptionFocus,
                    controller: recipeDescriptionController..text = _recipeDescription,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter recipe description',
                      border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                left: 0.0,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: 'saveBtn',
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (widget.recipe == null) {
                      Recipe _newRecipe = Recipe(
                          _recipeId,
                          recipeTitleController.text,
                          recipeDescriptionController.text
                      );
                      context.read<RecipeCubit>().createRecipe(_newRecipe);
                      //recipeRepository.createRecipe(_newRecipe);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    } else {
                      Recipe _newRecipe = Recipe(
                          widget.recipe!.id,
                          recipeTitleController.text,
                          recipeDescriptionController.text
                      );
                      context.read<RecipeCubit>().updateRecipe(_newRecipe);
                      //recipeRepository.updateRecipe(_newRecipe);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.save_outlined),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 24.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: _buttonVisible,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: 'deleteBtn',
                    onPressed: () {
                      context.read<RecipeCubit>().deleteRecipe(widget.recipe!.id!);
                      //recipeRepository.deleteRecipe(widget.recipe!.id!);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Icon(Icons.delete_outline_rounded),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

recipe_state.dart

```
part of 'recipe_cubit.dart';

abstract class RecipeState extends Equatable {
  const RecipeState();
}

class RecipeInitial extends RecipeState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class RecipeLoading extends RecipeState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class RecipeLoaded extends RecipeState {
  final List<Recipe> recipes;
  const RecipeLoaded(this.recipes);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [recipes];
}

class RecipeError extends RecipeState {
  final String message;
  const RecipeError(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

recipe_cubit.dart

```
part 'recipe_state.dart';

class RecipeCubit extends Cubit<RecipeState> {

  final RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

  RecipeCubit(this.recipeRepository) : super(RecipeInitial()) {
    getAllRecipes();
  }

  void getAllRecipes() async {
    try {
      emit(RecipeLoading());
      final recipes = await recipeRepository.getAllRecipes();
      emit(RecipeLoaded(recipes));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(const RecipeError('Error'));
    }
  }

  void createRecipe(Recipe recipe) async {
    await recipeRepository.createRecipe(recipe);
    final newRecipes = await recipeRepository.getAllRecipes();
    emit(RecipeLoaded(newRecipes));
  }

  void updateRecipe(Recipe recipe) async {
    await recipeRepository.updateRecipe(recipe);
    final newRecipes = await recipeRepository.getAllRecipes();
    emit(RecipeLoaded(newRecipes));

  }

  void deleteRecipe(int id) async {
    await recipeRepository.deleteRecipe(id);
    final newRecipes = await recipeRepository.getAllRecipes();
    emit(RecipeLoaded(newRecipes));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating another `BlocProvider` when you're navigating to `RecipeDetail` page. When you're pushing new `MaterialPageRoute`, this new page gets additionally wrapped in new `RecipeCubit`. Then, when you're calling `context.read<RecipeCubit>()`, you're referencing that provider (as this is closest `BlocProvider` in the widget tree). Your `RecipeList` can't react to those changes because it's `BlocBuilder` is looking for a `BlocProvider` declared above it in the widget tree (the one in `MyApp`).
Besides that, newly created provider gets removed from the widget tree anyway when you're closing `RecipeDetail` page as it is declared in the `MaterialPageRoute` which has just been pushed off the screen.

Try to remove the additional `BlocProvider` (the one in `RecipeList`, in `OnTap` function of `RecipeCardWidget`):

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return BlocProvider<RecipeCubit>(  // remove this BlocProvider
          create: (context) => RecipeCubit(RecipeRepository()),
          child: RecipeDetail(recipe: recipes[index]),
        );
      }
  ));
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer on this question. I removed the mentioned BlocProvider. Now, clicking the 'add' button still creates a new recipe after submitting the text fields (on recipe_detail page). But still no updated ListView without a refresh. And when I now click 'save' or 'delete' on recipe_list page I get this Error: Exception caught by gesture The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<RecipeCubit> above this RecipeDetail Widget ..... Got this Error before and thats why I added the BlocProvider

Comment: Oh, and could you move your first BlocProvider above MaterialApp in the widget tree? That way you'll have global access to it in your app. I forgot to mention this.

Comment: Ok, Error is gone. Now: When I click a ListItem and update/delete a recipe it updates automatically the ListView as it should. But when I click the 'add' button to create a new recipe it still updates the ListView only after a refresh. But so far thank you very much you helped me out a lot. EDIT: just removed the BlocProvider from the 'add' button as well. Everything works fine now. Thanks!